# How to monitor File Uploads without using Flash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I've been looking for a way to monitor file uploading information without using flash, but probably using ajax, i suppose. I want to monitor speed and percentage of finished file upload.

Do you know of any resource that describes how to do that, or what i should follow to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pre-HTML5 world I believe this requires web-server support.  I've used this Apache module successfully in the past:

http://piotrsarnacki.com/2008/06/18/upload-progress-bar-with-mod_passenger-and-apache/

Comment: well, it can be done with ajax for sure, i just don't know how this is done in Rails. But this source is very nice, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way without flash is to do it on the server.  The gist is:

- Start the file upload
- Open a streaming connection to the server
- Have the server read the post headers to tell you how large the file is going to be
- Have the server repeatedly check the file size (in /tmp generally) to see how complete it is
- stream the % done back to the client

I've done it before in other languages, but never in ruby, so not sure of a project that's done it, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, but i know that already. That is why i mention ajax. I'm looking for a how to.